# How do I get a list of all game IDs/names from the GOG api?

Tags: python

I am trying to store some basic data about the games on the gog store, but for my project I need a list of predefined IDs to iterate through.

```
import requests
data = requests.get("https://api.gog.com/products")
```

This just returns an empty string, but is the closest I have gotten so far.

Answer (score 2):

## `api.gog.com/products` require a path parameter

The snippet you provide returns an empty string because you aren't using the endpoint correctly. You need to send an int `product_id` as path parameter.

[gogapidocs > api.gog.com > get](https://gogapidocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/galaxy.html#api-gog-com)

> GET /products/(int: product_id)
>
> > Returns information about a product.

You might be interested in [gogapidocs: Game ID List](https://gogapidocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gameslist.html?highlight=list%20games#game-id-list):

> List of game’s names and their corresponding catalog IDs. Be aware that they sometimes don’t match up with the library IDs. For debugging purposes only, do not hardcode this list into your client!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this API doc doesn't have any information about getting all the game's names. So I'd like to suggest you use bs4 to get all the games' names. But if you need all games' JSON files you can get all game's ids and put them in the list. Then u can put that in for loops to get all JSON information.
You can use https://gogapidocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gameslist.html?highlight=list%20games#game-id-list this link to do web scraping.

```
    import requests
     ****
     ***
     *** this part for web scraping coding part 
     id_list[all games id where u get from bs4]
     for id in id_list:
          data = requests.get(f"https://api.gog.com/products/{id}")
```

Comment: if u have any questions about bs4 hit me up I'd be happy to help you

Comment: "Be aware that they sometimes don’t match up with the library IDs."

Comment: @DorianTurba u can do exception handling to don't match up id's.